# escaping forward slashes in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I am doing a general search against elasticsearch (1.7) and all is well except my account numbers have forward slashes in them.  The account number field is not the id field and is "not_analyzed".

If I do a search on an account number e.g. AC/1234/A01 then I get thousands of results, presumably because it is doing a regex search (?).

```
{
   "query" : { "query_string" : {"query" : "AC/1234/A01"} }
}
```

I can get the result I want by doing an exact match search

```
  {
    "query" : { "query_string" : {"query" : "\"AC/1234/A01\""} }
  }
```

This actually gives me the result I want and probably will fit the bill as a backup option (surrounding all 'single word' searches with quotes).  However I'm thinking if they do a multiple word search including the account number I will be back to thousands of results and although I can't see the value of that search I would like to avoid it happening.

Essentially I have a java app querying elastic search and I would like to escape all forward slashes entered in the GUI.

My Googling has told me that

```
{
  "query" : { "query_string" : {"query" : "AC\\/1234\\/A01"} }
}
```

ought to do this but it makes no difference, the query works but I still get thousands of results.

Could anyone point me in the right direction ?

Comment: Why are you using `query_string` here? `term` matches a term as it is.

Comment: There is one entry box for search terms which could be one word or a sentence, with or without boolean operators.  At the most basic it is querying all data.  It is working well except for the /.  As I understand it a term query can only query one field at a time (and I would have to parse the query myself to use a terms query I think) ?  Please do correct me if I'm wrong !

Comment: Main difference between `term` query and `match` and `query_string` is that the `term` is not analyzing the input. By using `term` query you can look for one term and by using `terms` you can do couple terms at once. Most appropriate for searching across multiple fields is `multi_match` or `query_string`. I have not checked but I think you could also use `term` query with alias `_all`, and "trick" `terms` query to look into more than one column at once.

Comment: Your problem seem to be incorrectly analyzed input. You store following tokens in index: `AC` on position 0, `1234` on position 1, `A01` on postion 2. Whereas you would probably want just one token `AC/1234/A01`. Enclosing account number in quotes works because by using quotes you enforce that "AC" precedes "1234" which which precedes "A01". But query string: `"\"AC/1234/A01\""` will match just as well `AC 1234 A01` and `AC|1234|A01`. In constrast after removing quotes it will match `AC a 1234 a b  A01`. Indexing this way would be useful if you would want to search by substrings,

Comment: Thanks, it's quite new to me (inherited code) so I'll look at the tokens in more detail, that sounds like it makes sense.  This query is a simplified query compared to the actual application which takes a list if fields which I don't believe term matches will fit the bill.  I have tried a match and multi_match query and they give the same results (which is why I stuck to the simplified query for the question), presumably because of the token issue you mention.  Many thanks I'll look at how we are using/building tokens in the index builder.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You should get what you want without escaping anything simply by specifying a [`keyword` analyzer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-keyword-analyzer.html) for the query string, like this:

```
{
  "query" : { 
     "query_string" : {
        "query" : "AC\\/1234\\/A01",
        "analyzer": "keyword"         <---- add this line
     } 
  }
}
```

If you don't do this, the standard analyzer is used (and will tokenize your query string) whatever the type of your field is or whether it is `not_analyzed` or not.

Comment: Many thanks, This seems to fit the bill.  I guess i need to understand it a little better before I put it into production (does it affect booleans and other more advanced searching techniques... time to do more study!) but that looks perfect.  Thanks very much.

Answer (score 2):

Use this query as example:

```
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "fields": [
        "account_number.keyword"
      ],
      "query": "AC\\/1234\\/A01",
      "analyzer": "keyword"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I use `query_string` because I want to give my users the possibility to do complex queries with OR and AND. Having the search break when a slash is used (e.g. when searching for an URL) is not helpful.

I worked around that issue by adding quotes when a slash is in the search string but no quotes:

```
if (strpos($query, '/') !== false && strpos($query, '"') === false) {
    $query = '"' . $query . '"';
}
```